# Display full image in background inc css

Tags: html, css

In my website there is a `<div>` with another div that is meant to display a bigger title with a smaller subtitle. It should look something like this:
[image]

In my case though it looks like this[:[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeAnW.jpg)

As you can see, the image is really squished and I am not really sure what I can do to display a "wholer" image. Here is my code.

```css
* {
    font-family: Oxygen;
    margin: 0px;
}

#s1 {
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1388069/pexels-photo-1388069.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}

#s2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#sf1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}

#sf2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#sf3 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="s1">
  <div id="s2">
    <div id="s3">
      <h1 id="sf1">Rechtsanwalt Thomas FORELL</h1>
      <h2 id="sf2">Ihre Anwaltskanzlei in Leun, Bamberg und Burbach</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3 id="sf3">Arbeitsrecht • Scheidungsrecht • Verkehrsstrafrecht • Ordnungswidrigkeitenrecht • Vertragsrecht</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add padding to your `#s1`:

```css
* {
    font-family: Oxygen;
    margin: 0px;
}

#s1 {
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1388069/pexels-photo-1388069.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding:100px 0;
}

#s2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#sf1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}

#sf2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#sf3 {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="s1">
  <div id="s2">
    <div id="s3">
      <h1 id="sf1">Rechtsanwalt Thomas FORELL</h1>
      <h2 id="sf2">Ihre Anwaltskanzlei in Leun, Bamberg und Burbach</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3 id="sf3">Arbeitsrecht • Scheidungsrecht • Verkehrsstrafrecht • Ordnungswidrigkeitenrecht • Vertragsrecht</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always **avoid** using **id** attribute for **styling**.

You can achieve your target with following code

**HTML**

```
<div class="s1">
    <div class="s2">
        <div class="s3">
        <h1 class="sf1">Rechtsanwalt Thomas FORELL</h1>
        <h2 class="sf2">Ihre Anwaltskanzlei in Leun, Bamberg und Burbach</h2>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
        <h3 class="sf3">Arbeitsrecht • Scheidungsrecht • Verkehrsstrafrecht • Ordnungswidrigkeitenrecht • Vertragsrecht</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and **CSS**

```
* {
  font-family: Oxygen;
  margin: 0px;
}

.s1 {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1388069/pexels-photo-1388069.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.s2 {
  padding: 80px 0;
  z-index: 3;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.s3 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  
}

.sf1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}

.sf2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sf3 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

hr {
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

Add `height: 100vh;` in #s1:

```css
#s1 {
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1388069/pexels-photo-1388069.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
```